# simulation of creation of social network graph given present snapshot

Tags: simulation, social-networking

I am using http://networkrepository.com/socfb-B-anon.php dataset for my analysis. I would like to do some analysis of how this present graph is formed from scratch. Is there any existing social network simulation framework for this kind of problem?

I am also open to use any other dataset if available. I would need the timestamp for every edge( nodes connected at).

Answer (score 0):

The [Barabási–Albert (BA) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) describes a *preferential attachment* model for generating networks, or graphs. It iteratively builds a graph by adding new nodes and connecting them to previously added nodes. The new node is attached to some other nodes with a probability proportional to the degree of the old node with relation to the total number of edges in the graph.

This algorithm has been shown to produce graphs that are *scale-free*, which means the distribution of degrees follows a *power law*, which is a typical property of social networks.

This can be seen as a 'simulation' of a growing social network, where users are more likely to 'befriend' or 'follow' popular existing users. Of course it's not a complete simulation because it assumes a new user is done befriending or following other users right after they created an account, but it might be a good starting point for your exploration.

A timestamp for each edge or node creation can be generated by maintaining one during the creation process and increment it as you add more edges or nodes to the graph.

Hopefully this answer gives you enough terminology to further your research.